# Find projection to linear orthogonal subspace using linear regression when matrix is not invertible

Tags: matrices, regression, linear-regression, projection-matrices

Task:

$X_1=(-2,6,3,-1)^T$

$X_2=(7,-3,-6,2)^T$

$X_3=(3,9,0,0)^T$

$Y=(2,-1,3,8)^T$

I need to find projection to Z, which is a linear projection. $Z$ should be expressed as $X_1,X_2$ and $X_3 $ combination. So basically I need to find distance between $Y$ and $L$. So I need to find $\hat{\beta}$

My solution:

First Let'S say that

$X=( X_1,X_2,X_3) $

I need to find $(X^TX)^{-1}$,

$$X^TX = \begin{bmatrix}
50 & -52 & 48\\
-52 & 98 & -6 \\
48 & -6 & 90
\end{bmatrix}$$

But I cannot find $(X^TX)^{-1}$ because it is not invertible.

Don't know where Can I get from here.

Comment: You need to find a basis for $Z=\text{span}\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$. The set $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ is not a basis for $Z$ and you need to identify and discard dependencies. Once you find those basis vectors then you can put them in the columns of $X$ and proceed.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Linear subspace